# Gasless transaction for student

Tags: solidity, web3js, dapps, gasless

i am developing a Dapp for the university and want the university to pay for student transaction i tried to use OpenZeppline github code but it is not working
i need a simple dapp which are using gassless transaction so that i would be able to use it

Answer (score 0):

You can use Biconomy for this purpose. Here is the documentation: https://docs.biconomy.io/quick-start/build-your-first-aa-powered-dapp

You can find the sample code here: https://github.com/Salmandabbakuti/gasless-dapp